# How can i get errors value inside Promise object which return from Fetch Api?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I have my fetch request like this.

```
fetch(deafaultUrl + '/v1/users/',
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(userInfoParams)
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.json());

            // not working never go into this function
            response.json().then(function(value) {
                console.log('access promise');
                console.log(value); // "Success"
            });

            if (response.status !== 200 && response.status !== 201) {
                throw new Error("Bad response from server");
            }
        })
        .then(function(json){

            console.log("succeed json re");
            console.log(json);
            dispatch(update_user(json));

        })
```

So when i console this `console.log(response.json());`

I got this

[image]

But it seems like Promise function doesnot workout.

So how can i get errors Object inside [[PromiseValue]]?

Thanks!

Comment: Why the double `then` ?

Answer (score 2):

To get the error from the promise, you can do it like this:

```
promise.then(function(data) {
  }, function(error) {...}
```

OR

To got promise error you can also use .catch() block

```
 .then(){...}
 .catch(){..}
```

Never going to this part because server already sent the response

```
.then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.json());

            // not working never go into this function
            response.json().then(function(value) {
                console.log('access promise');
                console.log(value); // "Success"
            });
```

You can write your code in this way:

```
fetch(deafaultUrl + '/v1/users/', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(userInfoParams)
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        // if request is successful
    }
    .catch(err){
         // if got error
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation of [`then(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

You should use it like this :

```
p.then(function(value) {
   // fulfillment
  }, function(reason) {
  // rejection
});
```

Then your code will look like this

```
fetch(deafaultUrl + '/v1/users/', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(userInfoParams)
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        //Land here if request is successful
        console.log(response);

        if (response.status !== 200 && response.status !== 201) {
            throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }
    }, function(error){
        //Land here if request has an error
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: This is not working even i got an error `422` response it stills go into the first block not the second one.

Comment: Go check what is the `422` error. The error is in your call

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution that `response.json()` can only read once if i get of `console.log(response.json());` it works fine.

Comment: This is correct. If you want to read it more than once, you need to clone the Response (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/clone).
Btw, that's not the righ way to log it. console.log(response.json()) will log the promise returned by the json() function, but you want to log the result, so response.json().then(data => console.log(data)).