# Use fetch(), read response body from non HTTP OK status codes and catch the exception

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, fetch

I have been reading up on `fetch()` and how to catch and print a readable error message from the server. Ideally I would like to throw an error that always ends up in `Catch 2` in my example below and that `` console.log(`OK: ${data}`); `` is not ran if there is an error. I can mitigate `` console.log(`OK: ${data}`); `` by running `then` directly on `response.json();` instead but I would like to know the proper way of achieving this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44576265/3850405

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

C#:

```
[HttpGet, Route("api/specific/catalog/test")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Test()
{
    return InternalServerError(new Exception("My Exception"));
}

[HttpGet, Route("api/specific/catalog/test2")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Test2()
{
    return Ok("My OK Message");
}
```

Typescript:

```
fetch('api/specific/catalog/test2')
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            response.text().then(text => {
                throw new Error(`Request rejected with status ${response.status} and message ${text}`);
            })
            .catch(error =>
                console.log(`Catch 1: ${error}`)
            );
        }
        else {
            return response.json();
        }
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(`OK: ${data}`);
    })
    .catch(error =>
        console.log(`Catch 2: ${error}`)
    );
```

OK:

[image]

Exception:

[image]

I guess I could do something like this to catch all errors but it seems weird:

```
fetch('api/specific/catalog/test')
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            response.text().then(text => {
                throw new Error(`Request rejected with status ${response.status} and message ${text}`);
            })
            .catch(error =>
                console.log(`Catch: ${error}`)
            );
        }
        else {
            return response.json().then(data => {
                console.log(`OK: ${data}`);
            })
            .catch(error =>
                console.log(`Catch 2: ${error}`)
            );
        }
    })
    .catch(error =>
        console.log(`Catch 3: ${error}`)
    );
```

Comment: Not even reaching a server is very different from the server answering with an error code and message. Your first catch2 will only catch malformed URLs or CORS stuff and the like. Purely from a JS perspective you can refactor the code so a single functions handles both exceptions. Just create a function and set it as `catch` handler for both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you swallow the error inside then, also you don't need multiple catches you only need one at the end like this:

```
fetch('api/specific/catalog/test')
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            return response.text().then(text => {
                throw new Error(`Request rejected with status ${response.status} and message ${text}`);
            })
        }
        else {
            return response.json()
        }
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(`OK: ${data}`);
    })
    .catch(error =>
        console.log(`Catch 3: ${error}`)
    );
```

Comment: Of course, totally missed to `return response.text()`. Thanks!