# Within a fetch() Promise, how to .catch server errors messages when status is 4xx or 5xx?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, es6-promise

In a locally run Node.js script, this works when status is 200:

```
// module file
import fetch from "node-fetch";
export const getJSON = () => {
  const url = 'https://api.somesite.com/api/v0/etc';
  const options = {method: 'GET', headers: {Accept: 'application/json'}};
  const request = fetch(url, options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(err => console.log("somesite:", err));
  return Promise.resolve(request);
};

// execution file
import { getJSON } from './libs/api_requests.mjs';
console.log("func call", await getJSON());
```

But the `fetch` also works without triggering the `.catch` logic when the response status is 4xx or 5xx (see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38236296/2066480)).

Execution doesn't break and I actually receive an error message when the function is called as if that would be the correct, normal result - as the output of `response.json()`.

This message is in plain English, something like "error: 'Incorrect path. Please check [https://www.somesite.com/api/'"](https://www.somesite.com/api/%27%22).

I would like to preserve/display this error message, only I would like to catch it within the function `getJSON` in the module file, instead of having to wrap some logic around it at the destination, potentially repeating the same code multiple times everywhere the function is called, instead of dealing with the issue just once at the source.

So I modified the `.then` clause like this, which also works:

```
.then(response => { if (response.ok) { // .ok should be status 200 only, I suppose
        return response.json();
      } else { throw new Error(response.status) }
```

This now triggers the `.catch` clause as intended, displaying "Error: 404 [etc]". Except what I would like to throw is the original error message "Incorrect path [etc]" and *that* I could not do. I tried

```
.then(response => { if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    } else { throw new Error(response.json()) } // somesite: Error: [object Promise]

.then(response => { if (response.ok) {
      return response.json()
    } else { throw new Error(Promise.resolve(response.json())) } // somesite: Error: [object Promise]

.then(response => { if (response.ok) {
      return response.json()
    } else { throw new Error(return response.json()) } // SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'return'

.then(response => { if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      } else { throw new Error(Promise.resolve(request)) } // somesite: Error: [object Promise]
```

I guess I need to resolve the `response.json()` promise as if all was ok, but how to do that?

I also had a look at the `request` object with `console.dir(request, { depth: null })` to see if I could extract the error message from there, but I couldn't find it and the object still contained many unexpanded elements like `[Function: onerror]` or `[Function: onclose]` for example.

Comment: Return Promise all([response.ok, response.json()]), check for errors in second .then()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `response.text()` instead of `response.json()` when the status code is `400` or `500`.
In my experience, the error messages are typically returned by the `text` callback.

---

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44576265/10475867) to a similar question.

---

Edit:

Added the following code, suggested by OP.

```js
.then((response) => {
  if (response.ok) {
    return response.json();
  }
  else {
     return response.text()
       .then((text) => {
         throw(text);

         // if the error is an object and you just want to display some elements:
         throw(JSON.parse(text));
       });
  }
})
.catch((err) => {
  // in case you want to log the error
  console.log("somesite: ", err));

  return new Error("somesite: " + err);
});
```

Comment: Same result: Error: [object Promise]. Thanks though!

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry I couldn't be more help!

Comment: So the answer at the link you indicated https://stackoverflow.com/a/44576265/2066480 actually solves the problem. Thank you very much. Only the execution of the script is not halted. Do I have to issue another throw within the '.catch' clause?

Comment: If you want the script to terminate because of an error, it will need to be `uncaught`. Throwing the error from within the `.catch` should work.

Comment: I'm stopping the script now with `.catch(err => {return new Error("somesite:: " + err)});` So this is also fixed. It's not pretty, but does the job.