# Get a readable error object when using fetch

Tags: javascript

I am calling an API using Javascript:

```
  fetch("/inquiries", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
    .then(response => {
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

When I submit invalid data I get an error which shows in console as:

[image: console log result]

If I access using a REST client I get:

[image: rest client result]

How to get the error response as it shows on my Rest Client?

**Update**

I tried the following:

```
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
  console.log(response.error);
  console.log(response.errors);
})
.catch((error) => {
});
```

And I got in the console:

[image]

If I check my network tab I see the response:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to get "The email is required" out of the data structure?

Comment: I think that it will be easier to get to `response.errors` to be an array of objects instead of an object or arrays? If you wanted to get the "The email is required" you will have to check any posible errors, but given that response you can get it with `response.errors.email`

Comment: That's weird... the promise shouldn't reject if the status is 400...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40408219/how-to-get-readable-error-response-from-javascript-fetch-api

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Readable error response from JavaScript Fetch API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40408219/how-to-get-readable-error-response-from-javascript-fetch-api)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have seen those question before but I haven't being able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that it will be easier to get to `response.errors` to be an array of strings instead of an object or arrays

If you want to access to the "The email is required" with the response that you provided you could get it with `response.errors.Email`

```
fetch("/posts", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
})

.then(response => {
   console.log(response.errors, response.errors.Email)
})

.catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

But With this error message structure that you provide you would "have" to check if any specific error is present in the response

```
if (response.errors.Email) {
  console.log(response.errors.Email)
} else if (response.erros.Password) {
  console.log(response.errors.Password)
} else if (response.erros.Other) {
  console.log(response.errors.Other)
} // and so on
```

If it was an Array of errors (strings/objects) you would simply loop on them, like

```
for (const error of response.errors) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

Comment: I tried `console.log(response.errors)` before and I get `undefined`. That's strange

Comment: and what `console.log(response)` outputs?

Comment: I added an update on my question with a few images that might help. What do you think?